# Dartlang does function can get params

Tags: dart

I am new at Dart language, but would like to find answer for the next question.
If I create global variable and function without input arguments.

```
num myVar = 0;
void IncrMyVar() { ++myVar; }
```

Then below in `main` declare the list of functions and add `IncrMyVar` as one of elemnt.

```
List<Function> a = new List<Function>();
a.add(IncrMyVar);
```

After all this steps I would like to call all functions from list `a`

```
for(Function foo in a)
{
 foo(myVar);
}
```

and will face with problem. Because `IncrMyVar` does not provide input params.

---

**So, my question is:**

**1**. How it be possible to check 'foo' that input params could be provided in function?

**2**. How would be better get exceptions in this case?

**3**. Is it possiable to call all functions list via 'a.forEach()' and somehow provide input params?

Comment: What do you mean with "somehow provide input params"? If the function doesn't declare input parameters, you can't pass some. What is the actual problem you try to solve? What do you mean with "better exception"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I am trying to find way to avoid situation, when function doesn't declare input parameters but I am trying to pass some into.

Comment: Ok, then my answer should fit. There is also reflection (`dart:mirrors`) but that's only available on server or console applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what the question is about exactly.

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
num myVar = 0;
void incrMyVar() {
  ++myVar;
}

void incrMyVar1(num value) {
  myVar += value;
}

typedef OneParam<P, R> = R Function(P param1);

void main() {
  List<Function> a = new List<Function>();
  a.add(incrMyVar);
  a.add(incrMyVar1);

  for (Function foo in a) {
    if (foo is OneParam<num, void>) {
    // alternatively inline
    // if (foo is void Function(num)) {
      foo(myVar);
      print('1 param');
    } else {
      foo();
      print('0 param');
    }
  }
  print(a);
}
```

A function type is used together with an `is` check to figure out if a function takes a parameter.